# Docker images for Google Cloud (GAE + Cloud Functions) node environments?

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm looking to exactly reproduce GCP execution environments for CI testing of Cloud Functions and/or AppEngine standard apps - specifically node 10. [These docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#runtimes) give the precise node version and indicate an "Ubuntu 18.04" base, but that's not a lot of detail to go on - my app is sensitive to the system version of `fontconfig` for example. Does anyone know a way?

Comment: The build of the App Engine container is managed by Google. This is not visible to you. If you require that level of control, switch to Cloud Run, Kubernetes or GCE+COS. If your goal is to clone an App Engine container, that should not be too difficult except for the vendor pieces that they never made public.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley, I may well move to Run. 99% of my stuff works fine on any old node environment but one particular native dependency I'm using to draw PNGs with a custom font is very pernickety. I've just come across https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docker which seems to be at least the basis for App Engine Flex - do you know of any pieces missing from that?

Comment: Your idea of moving to Cloud Run is good. Excellent service and you can control your containers with precision. For AE Flex, I do not know the answer but this is a Google Managed service similar to AE Standard. You cannot control the build process/contents.

Comment: Well, I'm not necessarily looking to _control_ the environment, just mimic it. With AWS Lambda I've used the `lambci/lambda` docker images in the past, but it looks like Google has no equivalent so controlling the build might be the only way. Thanks for your help.